# Is there a really simple way to make and IntSlider plot to the left of a figure in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, slider

I am confronted with a need to plot an ipywidget(IntSlider) to the left of a main plot for an online class and have spent the better part of 3 days trying to discern the method from online help and internet info.

In essence I have a bar plot created from 4 series.  On that plot I want a slider so the user can select the mean value to be assesed by the routine.  I started with the @interact method and have gotten nowhere at all.

Any guidance would be appreciated.